# text parsing then highlighting in textarea in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a neat way of highlighting texts in textarea on the fly while typing?

I would basically type in:

```
This is a [[note]] to do on friday.
```

on a textarea, then, using [a highlighting library](https://github.com/lonekorean/highlight-within-textarea), I would call it in like this:

```
    function FindAllNotes() {
        var note = /^(?:\[{2}(?!\[+))(.+)(?:\]{2}(?!\[+))$/g
        , input = ($(#textarea).val()).match(note);
           $(#textarea).highlightWithinTextarea({
            highlight: [input],
            className: 'yellow'
          });

    }
    $(#textarea).on('keyup', function () {
        FindAllNotes();
    });
```

But the problem is, everytime I type, it works and highlights notes enclosed in [[ ]], then I lose the cursor/focus on the textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin you linked to, can handle regular expression just as you want (*although you should remove the `^` and `$` from it, to not try to match the whole string*).

```js
$(function(){
  $('.example').highlightWithinTextarea({
    highlight: /(?:\[{2}(?!\[+))(.+)(?:\]{2}(?!\[+))/g,
    className: 'highlight'
  });
});
```

```css
.example{
  width:500px;
  height:250px;
}

.highlight{
  background-color:tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://lonekorean.github.io/highlight-within-textarea/jquery.highlight-within-textarea.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://lonekorean.github.io/highlight-within-textarea/jquery.highlight-within-textarea.css">

<textarea class="example">This is a [[note]] to do on friday.</textarea>
```

---

*keep in mind that you need to include the css file from the plugin which wraps/aligns the `textarea` with the `div` text*

Comment: Thank you very much for the help mate!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$("#textarea").focus();` to manually set the focus of a textbox. Maybe try calling this after your highlight function like the following:

```
$(#textarea).on('keyup', function () {
    FindAllNotes();
    $("#textarea").focus();
});
```